# How to open and run a existing Vagrant/Homestead project

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

I recently was given a Laravel/php project. I downloaded the project from gitHub and am trying to get it to run.

Here is a screenshot of the file system for the downloaded project:

[image]

Here is the file system of the homestead directory:

[image]

And here is my `homestead.yaml`:

```js
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: parallels

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

The project is ran using a Homestead/Vagrant setup, and I am trying to figure out how to do that. I have Homestead and Vagrant installed, could someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Do you have a virtual machine program installed like VirtualBox?

Comment: There should be Vagrantfile like here https://github.com/laravel/homestead to run it on Vagrant.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a straight download from gitHub and there is no Vagrantfile from it. I do have a virtual machine program installed, parallels

Comment: How can I tie in my downloaded github laravel project to my homestead server?

Comment: Would you be able to tell us the version of Laravel frame work the project is using? (Steps to do this. Open the composer.json file look under `"require"` then get the version of `"laravel/framework"`) I am just wondering so I can give you better setup advice.

Comment: `"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. What do you get back when your run `vboxmanage --version` and  also the output from `vagrant version` from your homestead directory on your local machine?

Comment: See your answer below. I think we are onto something magical!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the General rundown.....

1. So if your on Ubuntu or OSX you need to add `homestead.test` to your `/etc/hosts` file along and direct it to the ip address specified in your homestead.yml (Via the config you provided it's `192.168.10.10`)
2. Next: Go into your Homestead folder and run `vagrant provision`.

   **WHATS HAPPENING:** This will run "homestead's" provision script. (Per your config it will create a "homestead" database and map the Nginx config to your virtual machine's folder of `/home/vagrant/code/public`. It will also copy the contents of `~/code` (***might want to use an absolute file path.***) on your local machine to the virtual machine's folder of `/home/vagrant/code`. **So far everything is looking good in your config, but see my note on the file path**
3. Log into your vagrant box (aka: virtual machine) using `vagrant ssh`. (*if its down bring the box up with* `vagrant up`)
4. Navigate into that project directory in the virtual machine. `cd /home/vagrant/code/public`
5. Install packages by using composer command --> `composer install`
6. Things will break if you don't generate a encryption key for they project. You can generate one by running `artisan key:generate`
7. Hit your endpoint! Looks like you called yours `homestead.test`. If chrome stops your with a HSTS warning for ssl. (You can google how to **properly fix this issue.** In the meantime if you see that page you can type `badidea` and you can continue on)
8. If you have issue from here it could be database credentials stoping you. The default user name for your `homestead` database is `homestead` and the default password is `secret`.

I hope I was able to fill in the blanks that you may have encountered on your setup. Also keep in mind that your can run `php artisan serve --port=8080` on your local machine.( You will have to install missing packages manually via *[homebrew](https://brew.sh/)* or *`apt-get install`* [apt-get docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)) Information about this can be found on 
[Local Development Server Header](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/). https://laravel.com has great docs with small voids so also look there for further help. Good Luck!

So from you information provided above in your comment back to me your project is running Laravel Framework 4.2.*  . So the command I told you to run doesn't exist yet. (`artisan key:generate`) This command is only available in 5.* if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is amazing, I am getting to the point where I call `composer install` and I am getting this error on Homestead: `Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1` What does this mean?

Comment: See UPDATE. So just break down the error message. `Generating autoload files` that is good. `php artisan clear-compiled Mcrypt PHP extension required` I would say google that. (Your virtual machine is missing that extension) So fix that then we will go over the next error. BTW Just flat out giving your the answers goes against the sprit of stackOverflow. (research = learning).

Comment: I understand completely! I've been doing a crap ton of research on this, I am new to laravel so being thrown this project is going to be a challenge. I will get back to you shortly.

Comment: No worries I know your pain, same thing happened to me. Your in luck I use  Laravel on a daily basis. Hey side note if someone has the answer please don't forget to mark the correct answer and up-vote and down-vote comments. Also let me know if you need more clarification in my responses.

Comment: I will for sure. I am still hung up on this `Mcrypt PHP extension required` error. I have tried everything, yet I cant call `composer install`. I am ssh into my `vagrant@homestead` vm and ran many `sudo apt-get` calls, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you read the docs for `apt-get` that I supplied in my answer? Please google the error messages you're receiving. [LMGTFU Laravel Mcrypt PHP extension required](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mcrypt+PHP+extension+required&oq=Mcrypt+PHP+extension+required&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.315j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Trust me, I am doing a whole lot of googling and trying different tactics. I will keep trying. Yes, I did read about apt-get. I am missing a `php.ini` file. I think that could be my issue, because all solutions I am finding have something to do with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162461/discussion-between-edesilets-and-austin-hunter).

Comment: If anyone has this problem and are running php 7.2, DOWNGRADE YOUR PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Homestead docs: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

You'll likely need Virtualbox (If you don't already have it installed)

Comment: How can I tie the downloaded github project to my newly created Homestead project directory?

Answer (score -1):

If you have VirtualBox installed, you should be able to just run `vagrant up` from the Homestead project directory. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#launching-the-vagrant-box

Comment: How can I tie the github project to my Homestead project directory?

Comment: Oh, are you trying to convert an existing NON-HOMESTEAD Laravel project to work with homestead?

Comment: I was told they use vagrant/homestead to run the project. This is a freshly downloaded github project shown above. I want to run it in homestead using vagrant. I followed the docs but cant seem to get it to run.